# How can I customize font and page in laravel dompdf?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5.3, dompdf

I get from here : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

My controller is like this :

```
public function listdata()
{
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('print_tests.test_pdf');
    $pdf->setPaper('L', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf');
}
```

My view is like this :

```
<script type="text/php">

    if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        $x = 72;
        $y = 18;
        $text = "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
        $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("Arial", "bold");
        $size = 6;
        $color = array(0,0,0);
        $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $angle = 0.0;   //  default
        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
    }

</script>
```

I use this :

> "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.7.0",

When executed, the font is not Arial and the page is not display.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you loaded the "Arial" font into dompdf? The fonts available in a new install of dompdf are: helvetica, times (or times-roman), courier, dejavu sans, dejavu serif, dejavu sans mono, symbol, zapfdingbats. Plus the generic family names: sans, sans-serif, monospace.

Comment: @BrianS, How can I load the Arial font into dompdf?

Comment: The easiest way to set up a new font is to specify it in your CSS using an `@font-face` declaration. You need to pay attention to the [font-related configuration properties](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#configuration) for laravel-dompdf. The Dompdf [Unicode How-To](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo) covers the basics for adding a font.

Answer (score 7):

try in **laravel 5.5 above**.

1.first download the font which u want to add(or set) as **`.ttf`** extenstion

2.store inside laravel storage folder like this `storage/fonts/yourfont.ttf`

3.Use CSS **@font-face** rules inside your blade..

4.for example create `sample.blade.php` file  like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'yourfont'; //you can set your custom name also here..
            src: url({{ storage_path('fonts/yourfont.ttf') }}) format('truetype');
            font-weight: 400; // use the matching font-weight here ( 100, 200, 300, 400, etc).
            font-style: normal; // use the matching font-style here
         }        
        body{
            font-family: "yourfont",  //set your font name u can set custom font name also which u set in @font-face css rule
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Check your font is working or not...
</body>
</html>
```